# java - Max heap property not obeyed by PriorityQueue

Tags: java, algorithm, comparator, priority-queue, max-heap

I was trying out the problem [Top K Frequent Elements](https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/description/) and I am not asking for how its implemented but what is going wrong in my implementation.

My implementation idea:

1. Declare a `HashMap` to count the frequency of each number.
2. Declare a max heap with a `PriorityQueue` to keep track of the most frequent K elements.
3. Add elements to the `HashMap`.
4. Use a custom `Comparator` in the `PriorityQueue` so that it sorts its elements on the basis of the frequency from the `HashMap`.

My code is as follows:

```
public class TopKFrequentElements {
    private final HashMap<Integer, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(
            (a, b) -> {

                System.out.printf("a = %d b = %d, Freq(%d) = %d Freq(%d) = %d, Freq(%d).compareTo(Freq(%d)) = %d\n", a, b,
                        a, freqMap.get(a), b, freqMap.get(b), b, a, freqMap.get(b).compareTo(freqMap.get(a)));

                return freqMap.get(b).compareTo(freqMap.get(a));

            }
    );

    private void add(int num) {
        freqMap.put(num, freqMap.getOrDefault(num, 0) + 1);
        System.out.println("num = " + num);
        priorityQueue.add(num);
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }

    private int[] getK(int k) {
        int[] res = new int[k];

        int ct = 0;

        while (ct < k) {
            res[ct] = priorityQueue.peek();
            freqMap.put(res[ct], freqMap.get(res[ct]) - 1);
            priorityQueue.poll();

            while (!priorityQueue.isEmpty() &&
                    priorityQueue.peek()==res[ct]) {
                freqMap.put(res[ct], freqMap.get(res[ct]) - 1);
                priorityQueue.poll();
            }

            ct++;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public int[] topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {

        for (int num : nums) {
            add(num);
        }
        return getK(k);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopKFrequentElements elements = new TopKFrequentElements();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
                elements.topKFrequent(new int[]{3,0,1,0}, 1))
        );
    }
}
```

The code works as expected for all test cases expect this really interesting one:

- `{3,0,1,0} k = 1`

Here the output is `[3]` where it should be `[0]`.

I don't understand why this is happening, when the last `0` is added, then the `Comparator` of the `PriorityQueue` should preserve the invariant. But it does not.

Digging deeper I printed out when the Comparator is called and **I see that it is not comparing with all the elements.** Which I am unable to understand why.

```
num = 3
--------------
num = 0
a = 0 b = 3, Freq(0) = 1 Freq(3) = 1, Freq(3).compareTo(Freq(0)) = 0
--------------
num = 1
a = 1 b = 3, Freq(1) = 1 Freq(3) = 1, Freq(3).compareTo(Freq(1)) = 0
--------------
num = 0
a = 0 b = 0, Freq(0) = 2 Freq(0) = 2, Freq(0).compareTo(Freq(0)) = 0
```

As you can see the last addition for `0` is just calling the `Comparator` once when it should check with other values according to my intuition.

**Where are the calls for `3` and `1` ?**

What am I doing wrong? **I also cannot replicate this problem for any other example.**

What have I missed about the `PriorityQueue` implementation?

Comment: I assume that the `PriorityQueue` does not account for changing order, and it does not necessarily sort all elements, just the head is guaranteed to be the *least* element. When adding zero, it is compared to the head and the Comparator returns zero (equals) so no more elements need to be compared

Comment: @user16320675 Yes you maybe correct.

Comment: First accumulate freqs. Then sift them through PQ.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're trying to do here. If all you want is the top k from an array, you've gone about it in a very convoluted way. You're modifying the values stored in `freqMap` and using them to do comparisons in your `PriorityQueue` comparator. That's not going to work because `PriorityQueue` expects the relationships among the items in its backing array to be static: it doesn't automatically re-adjust every time you change the value of something in `freqMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the priority of an item is going to change on the fly, you need to remove the item from the queue and add it back, so that the `PriorityQueue` will reflect the change.

```
private void add(int num) {
    freqMap.put(num, freqMap.getOrDefault(num, 0) + 1);
    priorityQueue.remove(num);
    priorityQueue.add(num);
}
```

A more efficient way to approach it would be to calculate all the statistics for the priorities in advance, and then populate the priority queue. But you are also altering the priorities with each item you remove from the queue, so while this won't in your case, it would work in a similar case where the priorities are static.

```
// accumulate the statistics
var freqMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int num : nums) freqMap.merge(num, 1, Math::addExact);

// let's not refer to the mutable map on the fly
record PriorityInteger(int value, int priority)
        implements Comparable<PriorityInteger> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(PriorityInteger that) {
        if (this.priority != that.priority) {
            // sort highest priority values first
            return Integer.compare(that.priority, this.priority);
        }
        // for values of equal priority, sort in ascending order
        return Integer.compare(this.value, that.value);
    }
}

// create and populate the priority queue
var pq = new PriorityQueue<PriorityInteger>();
freqMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new PriorityInteger(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .forEach(pq::add);

// pull out the values and display them
while (!pq.isEmpty()) System.out.println(pq.poll().value());
```

#### Example

For a given set of data

```
int[] nums = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6 }
```

With four 2s they are they highest priority. Three 3s come next. At two apiece, the 1s and 6s are level pegging. The 4 is the lowest priority, with only a single entry.

#### Output

```
2
3
1
6
4
```

Comment: The problem is this fix renders PQ useless. `add` now has linear complexity (due to `contains` call).

Comment: Better to accumulate frequences in `freqMap` in a separate loop. Then filter them through the PQ of size K.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy That's a fair point but I was just trying to show the simplest change to the code in the question that would make it work. In practice, you are correct that it would be better to calculate all the frequencies first.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy I've added another example of what I agree is a better approach. Let me know if you see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @greybeard That's a good point. You're absolutely right. I've removed it from that version of the code.